# Java call nonvoid method for one value of many

Tags: java, methods, call

I have a nonvoid method with 4 int values, but i only want to "return" just one of those int values. I get an error message (below) in the statement where i call "calcpoints(final_points).

ERROR required: int,int,int,int
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

my code:

```
public static int calcpoints (int points, int total_points, int answer, int correct) {
  while ((points >= 0) && (answer != correct)) {
    System.out.println("Display problem");
    answer = GetInput.readLineInt();
    if (answer == correct) {
      total_points = total_points + points;
    } else { 
      points = points / 2;
    }
    total_points = total_points + points;
  }//end of while loop points
  return (total_points);
}//end of the calculate points method
```

Comment: How many arguments are you passing in?

Comment: how are you calling this method ?

Comment: i have 4 integer parameters in the call method, but only need to pass just one, but i guess java doesn't work that way. i only want to System.out.print one parameter, not all 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is defined with **4** *Integer parameters*

```
public static int calcpoints (int points, int total_points, int answer, int correct)
{

}
```

But in your method call, you are passing only **1** *parameter*, which is not right. You need to pass **4** *Integer parameters*

This is wrong: `calcpoints(final_points)`

This is right(for example): `calcpoints(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: Thanks. do i have to code all the parameters in the return statement? example: return (1, 2, 3, 4). i'm struggling because i only want to return one parameter in a system.out.println statement.

Comment: @user2899341: the method code is not at fault. Fix the method call, which you did not post, by the way.

Comment: my call method is System.out.println("Your score --> " + calcpoints(total_points);

Comment: **Passing** and **Returning** are two different things. While *passing* parameters to a method, you need to adhere to method definition. If your method definition has 4 parameters defined, you have to pass 4 parameters. As far as *returning* is concerned, you can only return *scalar(single)* value.